# sha1 and b is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 import hashlib

 email = 'email@m.com'
 pass = 'xxxxx'
 encrypted_password = hashlib.sha1(b(email + passw))
```

I have a problem because b is not recognized in this context and I need it to perform this operation. If I put b'astring' it will work.
How to resolve this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: `pass` is a reserved keyword in Python, please do create actual Python code. Do you mean you want to *encode* your strings?

Comment: In Python 3, the error message is *pretty clear*: `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`. And `b'...'` is a *literal syntax*, not a function. Have you tried `(email + passw).encode()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters this works thanks please post as answer and i'll choose you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the `b'...'` *syntax* for a function. It is not, it is a *notation* to create `bytes` objects, just like using `123` or `0xdeadbeaf` or `0o creates integer objects, and`[...]` creates a list.

The error message when you pass in a string tells you what to do:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Encode your string, using a suitable codec. If you want to support the full Unicode range for password characters (always a good idea), use a codec like UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32:

```
 encrypted_password = hashlib.sha1((email + passw).encode('utf8'))
```